# Why aren't the crashlogs from Testflight symbolicating in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, logging, crash, testflight

I just started getting crash reports from Testflights for a pre-release app that I'm working on, but for whatever reason Xcode isn't properly symbolicating the logs.

[image: This is what I'm seeing in Xcode]

The build is available (was built, archived and uploaded on this computer in this version of Xcode), so what am I missing here? Why aren't these crash logs symbolicated?

Comment: Have you tried downloading dSyms from the itunes Connect page?

Comment: I've selected download dSyms from the build page in Xcode.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently this is a bug that started happening when Apple started accepting bitcode. Not all of the dSYMs are downloaded when you click on 'Download dSYMs…' in the Xcode organizer. Here's how I fixed it:

1. Manually downloaded the dSYMs from the build page in iTunes Connect
2. Right-clicked on the crash log in Xcode and opened it in Finder
3. The xcrashpoint file you'll find is an archive, so right-click and show package contents
4. Drill down to your .crash file(s)
5. Copy the .crash file(s) to a different directory, for instance the desktop
6. Copy the dSYMs folder you downloaded to the same directory
7. Open Terminal, cd to the folder
8. In terminal, set the developer dir path:

`export DEVELOPER_DIR='/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer'`

9. Then symbolicate the files with (replace your paths and filenames here):

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash name_of_crashfile.crash name_of_downloaded_dSYMs_dir/ > output.log`

And voila! You have your symbolicated crash log.

Comment: A year later and I still have the same problem with Xcode 9 and Bitcode. Thanks @Christian Just to add, one can also just copy the `symbolicatecrash` executable into your folder in Step 5 so your command line is easier to remember :-)

Answer (score 2):

I still get this in Xcode 10. As a work around. Add the crash logs to your devices logs and they will be symbolicated. At least in my experience.

Step 1-
In Xcode Window>Devices & Simulators [select your device on the left]>view device logs.

Step 2-
Then Xcode> Window> Organizer > Crashes tab.
Right click a crash and click show in finder. This shows .xccrashpoint files. Right click> show package contents. Drill down into the folders until you see the .crash files. Then drag them into the device logs list we opened in step 1